# How to obtain patches from artery segmentation and store them in graphical form?

Tags: python, image-processing, graph, edges

I have image segmentations of arteries (Xray coronary angiography), and want to extract patches along the branches and store them in a graphical form so that it preserves the coronary tree structure.

An example of an artery segmentation image and the extracted centerline:

[image]

The centerline has been extracted using a skeletonisation algorithm, however, I am unsure how to extract points on the centerline and store them in a graph.

For example, I would want the result to look like this:

[image]

where I can get the x-y coordinates of the nodes, and also have the connecting edges, which will store the branch structure of the artery. Then, I will be able to take small 2D image patches at each node (the node will be the center point).

Comment: The top image is called a 'segmentation mask'.  There is no explanation of this term, there does not appear to be any relationship between this image and anything else in your question.  It seems like it could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm:

```
- Scan centerline image for location of nodes
   - Record x,y location of each dot, with a unique index number
- Scan centerlineimage for links between nodes
   - Record x,y locations of end points of each line, with a unique index number
- Loop over recorded lines
   - Record index number of closest dot to each line end point.
- Add dots connected by a line to adjacency matrix
- Store adjacency matrix in your favorite graph theory library.
```

The tricky part is scanning.  There are two ways:

1. Use a GUI and locate nodes and links by clicking when the mouse cursor is on them.  This is straightforward to code, but tedious if you have more than a few images to scan.
2. Image processing.  This is very complex to code, but multiple image scanning can be automated.

I have coded option 1 in C++.  Here is a screenshot

[image]

Usage:

**Scanning nodes**

- Select menu item X-ray.  User can browse through file folders and click om image file.  Image will appear on left
- Move mouse cursor over image.  Right click on node position.  Click on 'Node' in popup menu.  A yellow dot will appear on image and the co-ords and node index will be displayed on right.

**Scanning links**

- Move cursor over a node.  Left click. Click on 'link endpoint' in popup menu
- Move cursor over a second node. Left click. Click on 'link endpoint' in popup menu.  A blue line will appear on image between nodes.  The linked node indexes will display on right

The code for this application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/artery

FYI here is the public class interface for the nodes and link storage class

```
/// store of node locations and the links between them
class cArteries
{
public:
    /// add node location on x-ray image
    void addNode(const std::pair<int, int> &p);

    /// add link end location on x-ray image
    void addLinkEnd(const std::pair<int, int> &p);

    /// draw nodes and links on x-ray image
    void draw(wex::shapes &S);

    /// text describing each node
    std::vector<std::string> textNodes();

    /// text describing nodes connected by each link
    std::vector<std::string> textLinks();

    /// get adjacency matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> adjacencyMatrix();

private:
...
};
```

Comment: Hello! I have added some details into the question. Hopefully it is more clear now. Thanks a lot for your help! However, I want the graph to store the artery branches as well, and not just store patches one after the other sequentially. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the details.  In response I have updated my answer to be more specific and implemented a possible algorithm.

Comment: I have added a gettor for the adjacency matrix.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

[FilFinder](https://fil-finder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems like it can handle this job, specifically in its [skeleton and pruning section](https://fil-finder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#skeletons-pruning-length). (See in the link below where they have a graphical node representation of the filaments/segmentation.) The package analyzes filaments by turning them first into graphical form, which you can return. This process is automated with some entry parameters - if you follow their tutorial you'll be able to tune how stringent you'd prefer your nodes to be.

Once you obtain a list of nodes that FilFinder produces, you can use a node's coordinates to obtain a bounding box of your size preference to create image patches.

This is a no code answer, but I hope this serves as a rough guideline towards achieving your request.